# Redirect exactly null query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I have a lot of websites on my web server.

I just want to redirect all my websites when the url is exactly `/?`

For example:

- `www.example1.com/?`
- `www.example2.com/?`

but not like `www.example.com/x.php?`, `www.example.com/` or anything else.

I've tried many things but failed:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?_test [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\?$
RewriteRule  ^ http://www.example.com [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =="/?"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following codes for do that.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\?$ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

You define the rule as starts with ? and ends with that sign.

Comment: RewriteEngine On 
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ="/?"
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

this worked for me sagolasin kardesim

Comment: @Huseyin `^\?$` - this will never match in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_, since a literal `?` (question mark) is not part of the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches against. The URL-path matched notably excludes the query string, including the `?` prefix.

Comment: @MustafaMarsliTopaloğlu If `?` is a literal question mark in the request then `%{REQUEST_URI} ="/?"` would never match either? The `REQUEST_URI` Apache server variable does not include the `?` - signifying the start of the query string. In order to match a request for an empty query string (ie. `/?`) then you would need to match against `THE_REQUEST`.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect an empty query string (ie. when the URL simply ends with a `?`), you need to check against `THE_REQUEST`.

The `RewriteRule` pattern matches against the URL-path, which notably excludes the query string (including the `?`).

The `REQUEST_URI` *server* variable also omits the query string and any trailing `?`. (Note that this is different to the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable in PHP, which *does* include the full request URL.)

And the `QUERY_STRING` variable is empty regardless of whether a trailing `?` is present or not.

So, in order to *remove* (ie. redirect) a trailing `?` from the end of the URL, you can do something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ (.+)\?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R,L]
```

The trailing `?` on the end of the `RewriteRule` substitution (`%1?`) is not actually present in the resulting URL, but is required in order to *remove* the query string entirely. Alternatively, if you are on Apache 2.4+ you can use the `QSD` (Query string Discard) flag instead:

```
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,QSD]
```