# How do I redirect an url query string that has NO variables (through htaccess)?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

From a previous incorrect redirect directive in htaccess, these urls are now showing up in Google search console index ¨errors¨:

```
https://www.website.nl/category/page?
```

I would like to redirect the pages with a trailing ? to their proper canonical page, so without the question mark in it:

```
https://www.website.nl/category/page
```

It seems all online QandA pages on the subject always assume a query string with variables (field values). And that does not serve my purpose.

Although I think most of my websites do not use any query strings, I would like to have a htaccess redirect solution that only targets this particular issue and leaves any actual (complete) query strings alone.

Comment: The `QUERY_STRING` variable does not contain the question mark, so you won't be able to differentiate between `/page` and `/page?` by just checking if it is empty. You will need to check against the content of `THE_REQUEST` here.

Comment: In the listed duplicate (above), ignore the "accepted" answer (it is nonsense) and look at [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33437331/369434) below it!

Comment: However, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69543047/369434) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69542310/369434) is probably a better (newer) "duplicate", but since it has no upvotes I can't include it in the list above. [htaccess - cut out the question mark if there is one at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69542310/htaccess-cut-out-the-question-mark-if-there-is-one-at-the-end)

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks! The answer on the other duplicate question is probably the best solution and seems to be most compliant too